# Need help removing linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic and linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic

Tags: grub2, apt, kernel, dpkg

So I feel like a dunce having to post about this but, I need help trying to fix this issue, mostly because without the fix I can't install any new software or run updates. For some reason one of the kernals must not have been fully uninstalled (linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic), so I tried to do the first thing that came to mind: apt-get -f install... That fails and gives this:

```
cictrone@cictrone:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 201 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 241430 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic (3.16.0-34.47~14.04.1) ...
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.16.0-34-generic:No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.16.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic
Error! echo
Your kernel headers for kernel 3.16.0-34-generic cannot be found at
/lib/modules/3.16.0-34-generic/build or /lib/modules/3.16.0-34-generic/source.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-34-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.16.0-34-generic: No such file or directory
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.16.0-34-generic
Device driver support needs thus be built-in linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.16.0-34-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_raVmra/lib/modules/3.16.0-34-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_raVmra/lib/modules/3.16.0-34-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.16.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.16.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 39: /etc/default/grub: desktop-image=/home    /cictrone/Pictures/grub-splash.jpg: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic (3.16.0-34.47~14.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-34-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 39: /etc/default/grub: desktop-image=/home/cictrone/Pictures/grub-splash.jpg: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic
 linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've also tried:

1. sudo dpkg -C
2. sudo apt-get autoremove
3. sudo dpkg --remove
4. sudo dpkg --configure -a
5. sudo dpkg --remove  --force-remove-reinstreq
6. sudo apt-get autoclean

The output of my uname -r:

```
3.16.0-41-generic
```

The output of Terrance's suggestion:

```
cictrone@cictrone:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic linux-headers-3.16.0-34-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-3.16.0-34-generic is already the newest version.
linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic is already the newest version.    
linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/53.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic (--configure):
 package linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
Setting up linux-image-3.16.0-43-generic (3.16.0-43.58~14.04.1) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
initrd.img(/boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-43-generic) points to /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-43-generic
 (/boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-43-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-43-generic.postinst line 491.
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-43-generic) points to /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-43-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-43-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-43-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-43-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-43-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.16.0-43-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-43-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-43-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-43-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-43-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.16.0-43-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-43-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.16.0-43-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-43-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-43-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-43-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 39: /etc/default/grub: desktop-image=/home/cictrone/Pictures/grub-splash.jpg: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-43-generic.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.16.0-43-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up grub-pc (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.3+elementary10~ubuntu0.3.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-pc.config: 39: /etc/default/grub: desktop-image=/home/cictrone/Pictures/grub-splash.jpg: not found
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.16.0-43-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-43-generic depends on linux-image-3.16.0-43-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.16.0-43-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-43-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-lts-utopic:
 linux-image-generic-lts-utopic depends on linux-image-3.16.0-43-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.16.0-43-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic-lts-utopic depends on linux-image-extra-3.16.0-43-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-43-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-lts-utopic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-lts-utopic:
 linux-generic-lts-utopic depends on linux-image-generic-No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
lts-utopic (= 3.16.0.43.34); however:
 Package linux-image-generic-lts-utopic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-lts-utopic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic (--configure):
 package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic
     linux-image-3.16.0-43-generic
     grub-pc
     linux-image-extra-3.16.0-43-generic
     linux-image-generic-lts-utopic
     linux-generic-lts-utopic
     linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The following is the output from the remove command after issueing the reinstall command (apt-get):

```
cictrone@cictrone:~$ sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic linux-headers-3.16.0-34-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.16.0-34
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-3.16.0-34-generic linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 215 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 271286 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic (3.16.0-34.47~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.16.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-34-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.16.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.16.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 39: /etc/default/grub: desktop-image=/home/cictrone/Pictures/grub-splash.jpg: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic (3.16.0-34.47~14.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/prerm.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/prerm.d/dkms 3.16.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic
dkms: removing: bcmwl 6.30.223.248+bdcom (3.16.0-34-generic) (x86_64)

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  bcmwl
Version: 6.30.223.248+bdcom
Kernel:  3.16.0-34-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

wl.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.16.0-34-generic/extra/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod....

DKMS: uninstall completed.
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-34-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 39: /etc/default/grub: desktop-image=/home/cictrone/Pictures/grub-splash.jpg: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-headers-3.16.0-34-generic (3.16.0-34.47~14.04.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic
 linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

These ubuntu tweaks tool (was able to get it installed) also sees the kernel but gives same errors as the terminal.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

****Solved****

It turned out that the kernel issue wasn't the cause of holding aptitude up. It was actually grub.The line in particular :

```
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 39: /etc/default/grub: desktop-image=/home/cictrone/Pictures/grub-splash.jpg: not found
```

I went it to the file and deleted the line with the problem and then ran Terrence's suggestions and everything is fixed! Thanks Everyone.

Comment: How about apt-get update before apt-get remove?

Comment: I cannot run apt-get update without rnning into the same issue that is show in the -f install output

Comment: remove the image and then the headers in different steps.

Comment: Tried doing them one by one and it didn't work, thanks for the attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reinstalling that kernel then remove it.

**Reinstall:**

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic linux-headers-3.16.0-34-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic
```

**Remove:**

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic linux-headers-3.16.0-34-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately it did not work, i will post the output above.

Comment: @NicholasO'Brien I edited one thing.  Can you try it again with the `--reinstall` added to the reinstall line?  I am hoping that we can get this all solved for you.  =)

Comment: Uggh No dice... I'll post the new output above thanks again

Comment: @NicholasO'Brien very nice to see that you have it fixed!  Hope you have a great weekend!  =)

Answer (score 0):

Give [Ubuntu-Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) a try.  It removes old kernels well for me.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot install the dependencies for it because of this issue. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

What's the running-kernel?

You need to pay attention to this:

```
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/prerm.d/dkms 3.16.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic
dkms: removing: bcmwl 6.30.223.248+bdcom (3.16.0-34-generic) (x86_64)

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  bcmwl
Version: 6.30.223.248+bdcom
Kernel:  3.16.0-34-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.
```

Comment: 3.16.0-41-generic is the running kernal... I am curious as to why 3.16.0-34-generic was marked active. Any ideas on how to set it to inactive, Thanks for your response btw.

Comment: the bcmwl modules is actived and in 3.16.0-34's dir. You need to try to re-compile/re-install this driver/package for your current kernel.  [link]http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/bcmwl-kernel-source [link]https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl